# copy into table in postgresSQL from csv files

Tags: python, postgresql, csv

what am I doing wrong?

```
file_list = glob.glob("test/*")
for file in file_list:
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    print(file)
    file_name = file.split("\\")[1].replace(".csv", "")
    cur.execute("COPY {table_name} FROM '{file_path}' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;".format(
        table_name=file_name,
        file_path=file
    ))
```

I get an error

```
UndefinedFile                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [83], in <cell line: 2>()
      4 print(file)
      5 file_name = file.split("\\")[1].replace(".csv", "")
----> 6 cur.execute("COPY {table_name} FROM '{file_path}' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;".format(
      7     table_name=file_name,
      8     file_path=file
      9 ))

UndefinedFile: could not open file "test\appearences.csv" for reading: No such file or directory
HINT:  COPY FROM instructs the PostgreSQL server process to read a file. You may want a client-side facility such as psql's \copy.
```

I have no idea what is wrong. Files are ok, path also couse i can read files into dataframes.

Comment: wrong path separators `("test/*")` - `file.split("\\")`

Comment: 1.) `psycopg2` has [`copy_from`](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_from) method. 2.) Why at all do you split the filename ?

Comment: The SQL statement COPY can only work when your database server has direct access to the file that you want to read. That file can not be on a different (virtual) machine. Advice: Use copy_from, that is so much easier and gives you to option to separate the application server from the database server.

Comment: Assuming the files are actually CSV(it would helpful to add a sample to your question), then look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75408821/python-psycopg2-loading-csv-file-with-quote-and-comma-delimiter/75421750#75421750) for a possible solution.