# loading dataset into postgreSQL through python

Tags: python, postgresql

i couldn't load the csv dataset into posgresql through python

i made connection python then create table with same columns and that was done successfully, but the loading or copying rest of data from the external csv into created table was not working with me and that to perform the postgresql queries the code  is as follow

```
import psycopg2
import csv
conn = psycopg2.connect(database = "dev", 
                        user= 'postgres',
                        host= 'localhost',
                        password = "1437",
                        port = 5432)

cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE info_v3(
            product_name varchar(50),
            product_id int PRIMARY KEY,
           decription varchar(100));
            """)
# Make the changes to the database persistent
conn.commit()
cur = conn.cursor()
df = pd.read_csv('..\info_v2.csv')
with open(df, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader) # Skip the header row.
    for row in reader:
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO info_v3 VALUES row"
    )
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python psycopg2 loading csv file with quote and comma delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75408821/python-psycopg2-loading-csv-file-with-quote-and-comma-delimiter)

Comment: 1) You don't need to use Pandas, `psycopg2` has a  built in methods for working with CSV files here [COPY](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#using-copy-to-and-copy-from). In particular [copy_expert](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_expert). Also `COPY` will be a lot faster then `INSERT`.2) You need to read up on using [Parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) in a query.